# Separator appears in uitableview while disabled

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm creating an iOS app using swift. I want to build a non scrollable tableView which shows on screen all informations contained in datasource, so the height of each cell depends on the number of entries in data. For example, if the height of the view is 500 and data.count = 10, each cell's height is 50. A problem appears when the cell's height is ~100.8 (corresponding to 5 entries in my data, using my iPhone 5). In fact, even by setting `tableView.separatorStyle = .None` , a weird separator appears for this cell's height.

Below, the first image (7 entries in data) is normal and on the second (5 entries in data) those separators appear.

[image: for 7 entries, no problem]

[image: for 5 entries, problem]

Here is my view controller :

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"
    var data = ["bobby", "bob", "john", "helena", "clara", "oliver", "steve"]
    var visibleHeight:CGFloat!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        edgesForExtendedLayout = .None
        tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        editModeOff()
        tableView.scrollEnabled = false
        visibleHeight = viewVisibleSize.height
        tableView.separatorStyle = .None
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return data.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel!.text = data[indexPath.row]
        cell.selectionStyle = .None
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let stringToMove = data[sourceIndexPath.row]
        data.removeAtIndex(sourceIndexPath.row)
        data.insert(stringToMove, atIndex: destinationIndexPath.row)
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .Delete{
            data.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
        }
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        print(visibleHeight/CGFloat(data.count))
        return visibleHeight/CGFloat(data.count)
    }

    func editModeOn(){
        tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Done, target: self, action: "editModeOff")
    }

    func editModeOff(){
        tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Edit, target: self, action: "editModeOn")
    }

}

extension ViewController{

    var viewVisibleSize:CGSize{
        var size = view.bounds.size

        if !UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarHidden{
            size.height -= UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.height
        }

        if let navigationController = navigationController{
            size.height -= navigationController.navigationBar.bounds.height
        }

        if let tabBarController = tabBarController{
            size.height -= tabBarController.tabBar.bounds.height
        }

        return size
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I always clear the color of the separator:

```
 tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

Comment: I already tried that. Didn't work... I tried to set all possible colors (background, separator, cell...) to white/clear but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a dirty solution by setting :

```
cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
cell.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
```

in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. But for sure, there is a better way...

Answer (score 0):

In your `viewDidLoad:` you can try `self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()`

Answer (score 0):

It is funny. Problem in your function 
 tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat 
It has strange behavior for some float numbers and a separator will appear. 
I offer you round a returning height like this:

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        print(self.visibleHeight/CGFloat(self.tableArray.count))
        let rett = self.visibleHeight/CGFloat(self.tableArray.count)
        let convert = NSString(format: "%.0f", rett)
        return CGFloat(convert.floatValue)
    }
```